# Query multiple results in Dapper asychronously

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I am trying to fix an issue with an existing code and not sure if this approach is correct or not as I have not worked with dapper before. I am trying to return a list of objects using a stored procedure.

The code below compiles but I am not sure if this is the correct way to return multiple rows or not. Is there anything that just returns to list rather than me looping through and constructing list and then returning?

```
public async Task<List<Event>> GetEventsAsync()
{
   await using SqlConnection db = new(this.settings.ConnectionString);
       
   List<Event> events = new List<Event>();

   var eventsMarkedPublished =  await db.QueryAsync<Event>("[sp_get_published_events]", null, commandTimeout: 60, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

     foreach (var pubEvents in eventsMarkedPublished)
     {
        events.Add(pubEvents);
     }

     return events;
 }
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to return `List` by `ToList` method directly.

```
return (await db.QueryAsync<Event>("[sp_get_published_events]", null, commandTimeout: 60, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)).ToList();
```

or

```
var result = await db.QueryAsync<Event>("[sp_get_published_events]", null, commandTimeout: 60, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
return result.ToList();
```

Comment: thank you.. I did this and it seems to be cmpiling correctly :  var result =  await db.QueryAsync<Event>("[sp_get_published_events]", null, 
               commandTimeout: 60, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            return result.AsList<Event>();

Comment: `result` needs a `using`

Comment: @Charlieface: In the question there's a using on the first line. That should cover this solution as well.

Comment: I don't think that makes any difference, that's for the connection not the reader. What does make a difference is whether it's a buffered command, which in this case it is (it's the default). See source code https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/blob/ca00feeb5fafe5262166689c0bec2b80b53add4e/Dapper/SqlMapper.Async.cs#L432 Still probably best practice to have a `using`, it's not like it costs